# Read file until specific line in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, file, file-read

I have one text file. I am parsing some data using regex. So open the file and read it and the parse it. But I don't want to read and parse data after some specific line in that text file. For example

```
file start here..
some data...
SPECIFIC LINE
some data....
```

Now I don't want to read file after SPECIFIC LINE...
Is there any way to stop reading when that line reaches?

Comment: Yes, but what will you be doing with the file after that?

Comment: A `for` loop with a `break`?  This is pretty standard ... can you show us your efforts so we can help you rather than just requesting we do it for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward, you can terminate a loop early with a `break` statement.

```
filename = 'somefile.txt'

with open(filename, 'r') as input:
   for line in input:
       if 'indicator' in line:
            break
```

Using [`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343) creates a compound statement that ensures that upon entering and leaving the scope of the `with` statement `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` will be called respectively.  For the purpose of file reading this will prevent any dangling filehandles.

The [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) statement tells the loop to terminate immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Use `iter()`'s `sentinel` parameter:

```py
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in iter(lambda: f.readline().rstrip(), 'SPECIFIC LINE'):
        print(line)
```

output:

```
file start here..
some data...
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter

Answer (score 0):

**Read only first `n` lines** without loading the whole file:

```
n = 5
with open(r'C:\Temp\test.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    head = [next(f) for x in range(n)]
```